# Why using Stack memory instead of Heap memory by Schrift will cause exception/malfunction in rendering in ESP32

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory, esp32

I try to use **Schrift open source library** for true type font display in my **ESP32** project. First I write a thin program to test the Schrift in Windows (GCC compiler) and it runs perfectly (just print some font char to the LCD/screen).  Then the same code move to the ESP32 platform, however, there is multiple problem, first is compilation error which I have solved, second is the run time malfunction/exception and I have fixed too.  But I still not quite understand why it does not work in original code and hope it can be explained by stackoverflow experts :)

the problem appear in the internal rendering API, the STACK_ALLOC is the macro that dynamically decided to use stack memory or heap memory, I don't see any problem with this macro and it runs perfectly in PC, however, I found that this is the critical line to generate the exception/malfunction under ESP32 environment.  If using STACK_ALLOC macro, it could have 2 results: first is exception would happen after a few char decoding.  second is font rendering not working at all if I add one more line of code in main() just for printing the 1st 32bytes of bitmap content to monitor the result, the bitmap of font character cannot be output from sft_render().    **After force STACK_ALLOC to simple calloc(), the whole things works properly**.  Now question is **why the macro STACK_ALLOC does not work?** (why stack memory does not work in ESP32?)

note: both stack and heap memory is not running out in ESP32, it does not help even I expand the stack memory of the task.

```
/* source code from Schrift.c, Allocate values on the stack if they are small enough, else spill to heap. */
#define STACK_ALLOC(var, type, thresh, count) \
    type var##_stack_[thresh]; \
    var = (count) <= (thresh) ? var##_stack_ : calloc(sizeof(type), count);
#define STACK_FREE(var) \
    if (var != var##_stack_) free(var);


static int
render_outline(Outline *outl, double transform[6], SFT_Image image)
{
    Cell *cells = NULL;
    Raster buf;
    unsigned int numPixels;
    
    numPixels = (unsigned int) image.width * (unsigned int) image.height;

//  STACK_ALLOC(cells, Cell, 128 * 128, numPixels);  // removed by Chris
    cells = calloc(sizeof(Cell), numPixels);         // added by Chris
    if (!cells) {
        return -1;
    }
    memset(cells, 0, numPixels * sizeof *cells);
    buf.cells  = cells;
    buf.width  = image.width;
    buf.height = image.height;

    transform_points(outl->numPoints, outl->points, transform);

    clip_points(outl->numPoints, outl->points, image.width, image.height);

    if (tesselate_curves(outl) < 0) {
//      STACK_FREE(cells);    // removed by Chris
        free(cells);          // added by Chris
        return -1;
    }

    draw_lines(outl, buf);

    post_process(buf, image.pixels);

//  STACK_FREE(cells);     // removed by Chris
    free(cells);           // added by Chris
    return 0;
}
```

below is the tracelog msg from ESP32, it shows both run time stack and heap memory size is not running out, library is working fine up to decoding font metrix information, the exception reported is due to watchdog after decoding from 'a' to 'E'

```
I (810) UKKan: Position 8, Char e bitmap width/height=10/18, left/yOffset=0.990234/-16 round=1, advance=10.105469 round=10
I (820) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (830) UKKan: Free heap size: 326192 bytes

I (830) UKKan: Position 9, Char E bitmap width/height=10/24, left/yOffset=1.688477/-23 round=2, advance=11.070312 round=11
I (840) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (850) UKKan: Free heap size: 326068 bytes

ESP-ROM:esp32s3-20210327
Build:Mar 27 2021
**rst:0x8 (TG1WDT_SYS_RST)**,boot:0x8 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
Saved PC:0x403791ea
0x403791ea: _xt_panic at C:/Users/CKan/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/port/arch/xtensa/panic_handler_asm.S:29

SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fce3818,len:0x16e4
load:0x403c9700,len:0x4
load:0x403c9704,len:0xc00
load:0x403cc700,len:0x2eb0
entry 0x403c9908
I (31) boot: ESP-IDF v5.1-dirty 2nd stage bootloader
I (31) boot: compile time Dec 11 2023 10:45:35
I (31) boot: Multicore bootloader
I (35) boot: chip revision: v0.1
I (39) boot.esp32s3: Boot SPI Speed : 80MHz
I (43) boot.esp32s3: SPI Mode       : DIO
I (48) boot.esp32s3: SPI Flash Size : 8MB
W (53) boot.esp32s3: **PRO CPU has been reset by WDT**.
W (58) boot.esp32s3: **APP CPU has been reset by WDT**.
I (64) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
```

another tracelog on ESP32 is adding a print of image buffer to check whether the font bitmap is draw but I found memory content is not changed at all after sft_render() call (ie. this function didn't draw anything to my provided buffer).  (but I have to emphasis the whole library works in Windows PC environment, also the same thing works after I replace STACK_ALLOC with calloc)

```
I (633) UKKan: Whole LCD update done!
I (633) UKKan: Position 0, Char a bitmap width/height=10/18, left/yOffset=1.218750/-16 round=1, advance=10.587891 round=11
I (643) UKKan: ec 25 ca 3f ec 25 ca 3f 82 34 cd 77 e1 b7 f0 fc
I (643) UKKan: b7 f5 77 ed ba b5 2b 60 87 3c de bc 41 3a 17 42
I (653) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (663) UKKan: Free heap size: 326192 bytes

I (663) UKKan: Position 1, Char A bitmap width/height=13/24, left/yOffset=0.990234/-23 round=1, advance=13.482422 round=13
I (673) UKKan: ec 25 ca 3f ec 25 ca 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
I (683) UKKan: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
I (693) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (693) UKKan: Free heap size: 326060 bytes

I (703) UKKan: Position 2, Char b bitmap width/height=10/25, left/yOffset=1.231445/-23 round=1, advance=10.587891 round=11
I (713) UKKan: ec 25 ca 3f ec 25 ca 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
I (723) UKKan: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
I (723) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (733) UKKan: Free heap size: 326120 bytes
```

I have confirmed the problem is due to STACK_ALLOC macro, replacing it by calloc() will solve the problem and Schrift will work as expected.  From the run time message I know the stack and heap memory are not running out, just don't know why STACK_ALLOC does not work in ESP32

Comment: What is a `Cell` in your code? How large is it? In your `STACK_ALLOC` macro you only use the `count` to compare with threshold, no matter how large each element is. Also, what is the purpose of that threshold at all? You allocate the array on the stack anyway.

Comment: "the STACK_ALLOC is the macro that dynamically decided to use stack memory or heap memory" No, it decides to use stack memory only or stack memory and heap memory. To avoid using stack memory it would be required to evaluate the condition at compile time and optimize the array away which you should not rely on.

Comment: I am not familiar with these traces. Where do you see a free stack size? How large is it? Also, how large is your total stack and how large is the image you pass to that function?

Comment: the code is cut from Shrift lightweight true type lib, it is hosted in GitHub   https://github.com/tomolt/libschrift ,  I think his STACK_ALLOC is used to determine using a faster stack memory for small size or using heap memory for larger than the threshold.  Schrift comes with a demo program in c running in XWindows.  At least I know his code works in XWindows and Windows as well, and STACK_ALLOC is the cause of exception/malfunction in ESP32 environment.

Comment: On Windows or other PC systems stack memory is more likely to be large enough to hold your data. If you switch to a microcontroller, you need to take care about your memory more strictly. Please include relevant information (size of your data types, stack size, free stack size if available, dimensions of the image) directly into the question.

Comment: `I (723) UKKan: Remaining app_main() stack size: 5244 words
I (733) UKKan: Free heap size: 326120 bytes`             free stack size for my task is 5k while free heap size is 300k, stack size is not running low, and I checked the function render_outline() is not returning error -1, it returns 0

Comment: Ok, got it. If you put an array on your stack that is larger than the whole stack, that free stack detection might not work properly. I found `Cell` to be 2 `double`s. But how many of them do you put on the stack and how large is the stack in total?

Comment: it didn't looks like a stack overflow because I dump the first 32byte of the bitmap it is not updated, ie. the rendering is not drawing anything, it returns 0 telling it is working, my stack monitoring still shows 5k (it tells the remaining after the deepest call tree in the task loop, it should include all those local variable usage). But of course I have some suspect on the stack therefore I force STACK_ALLOC to calloc() and found that it works.  But can we say this is a stack overflow problem from these observation?

Comment: more information:   `numPixels = (unsigned int) image.width * (unsigned int) image.height;`      this is the character bitmap's size, so width and height is less than 25, the numPixels should be very small

Comment: I think @Gerhardh is right about this is likely a stack overflow, if 8byte double, then Cell is 16byte, 20x20 size font may required more than 5k so it could cause variable kind of exception.  Watchdog may due to function is not able to return correctly so Watchdog not the real cause.

Comment: Stack usage mechanisms might only check within the limits of the stack. If you put some array on the stack, that is larger but is not used as you do that `STACK_ALLOC` thingy, you might corrupt areas that are completely outside your stack but go unnoticed by the stack usage detector.

Comment: In C it's the developer's job to ensure that they're not overflowing their stack. Some RTOS's or platforms help you with that, but they don't catch all the possible errors. Superficially to me this almost certainly looks like a stack overflow issue, particularly since it goes away when you use your orders-of-magnitude larger heap instead. You write that you "expand the stack memory of the task" - but by how much? If you're determined to use the stack then you need to calculate how much space your objects will take and allow for that space (plus more).